# How to manage web drivers via jenkins - jmeter webdriver script?

Tags: performance, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jmeter-plugins, webdriver-manager

I have to build JMeter script using JSR223 Sample for chrome, I was wondering if there is a way that I can configure path in the script so that I don't need to host drivers in Jenkins.
In Selenium Automation, I used webdriverManger to download new driver every time https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/webdrivermanager/

**JSR223 Sampler:**

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    **System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/geckodriver");**
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    def wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    driver.get('https://google.com/');
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@name='q']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in JMeter:

1. Download WebDriverManager ["fat" jar](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager#webdrivermanager-cli) from the [releases page](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/releases/) and drop it to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation or at any other place in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Replace your

   ```
   **System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/geckodriver");**
   ```

   with

   ```
    io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup()
   ```
4. Enjoy

More information and another trick you can play: [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time)

Comment: Issue resolved , much appreciated for your support.